# navigation wix v2-v3 not hiding bottom tab properly

Tags: ios, react-native, navigation, velo

I'm trying to dynamically hide the bottom tabs whenever a filter modal shows up from bottom to top under the same screen.
But for some reason, the bottom tab container (white) doesn't slide down.

This is how I use the Navigation.mergeOptions:

```
toggleFilter() {
        var shouldOpen = !this.state.filterOpened;

        Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
            bottomTabs: {
                visible: shouldOpen ? false : true,
                drawBehind: shouldOpen ? true : false,
                animate: shouldOpen ? true : false
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            filterOpened: shouldOpen
        });
    }
```

This is how it looks at the bottom:
[image]

**EXTRA INFO:** 
I just tested without opening the modal, trying to hide it on the same screen, and it happens the same, so this isn't a problem of my modal.
Thought that this would be also related to ScrollView/FlatList but it wasn't, tested it on a simple View with Flex and it happens as well. It should be easy to replicate.

Any idea about this issue? Thanks!

Some environment information:

```
React Native Navigation version: ^3.0.0-alpha.0
React Native version: ^0.60.0
Platform(s): iOS (Haven't tested on Android yet)
Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Real iPhone XS latest iOS version.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in RNN. Hiding BottomTabs with animation isn't supported on iOS and was added as a PR to RNN. That PR probably didn't take this use case into account.

Your best option for now is to draw the screen behind the BottomTabs by setting `drawBehind: true` in static options, and to handle the bottom padding your self.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i will test it out and let you know :)

Comment: i can't seem to understand how that works. You mean i should add a paddingBottom to the View container? or where?

Comment: Yes. add `paddingBottom` to the root view in jsx and add `bottomTabs { drawBehind: true }` to static options of your screen.